# Is there a way to inline SizzleJS when using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, sizzle

I need to inline Sizzle into a TypeScript class, so I can use it from within the class. I can live with not having a definition file for it and just have it as an "any". However the compiler is raising errors from within the minified Sizzle code if I put it at the top of the file. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to keep it in a JavaScript file and just add a declaration for the bits you need in your TypeScript file - but you have specifically asked for how you could get it inline in a TypeScript file, so here is the answer to your question...

You could butcher-in some type annotations and type assertions in order to "get away with it" - although it would be quite a brute...

I have put the full version online as it is too big to place here, but in essence I have either prefixed an expression with a type assertion:

```
var high = <any>"0x" + escaped - 0x10000;
```

Or added a type annotation:

```
var addCombinator: any = function( matcher, combinator, base ) {
```

To any item where the inferred types get violated. You could of course place a reasonable type annotation rather than any if you prefer.

[Fully annotated Sizzle](http://pastebin.com/mLfA4Lzn).

Comment: I was afraid that was my best bet. I am not crazy about this route, because I then have to do changes each time I wish to upgrade to a new version of Sizzle. I also still have to define types because Sizzle() is registered on window or the function in which it is declared - which the compiler does not see. So it feels like a hack, and I really need to get around having two dependencies.

Comment: What else are you using in your program? For example, could you use bundling to combine the two files later in your work-flow (i.e. work on them as two files, but combine the JavaScript output from your TypeScript file with the sizzle file, so you still end up with just one dependency?

Comment: I am just looking into that. It won't make the choice easy for me though - because I feel like I am adding quite a bit of complexity/steps just to get the reduction in complexity that typescript brings. So all in all I might be better off with pure js - which feels sad..